# BOX Integration: Decrypt Private Encrypted Key

Tags: openssl, jwt

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted private key to connect to Box as per instructions [here](https://developer.box.com/guides/authentication/jwt/without-sdk/#2-decrypt-private-key).

I am trying to decrypt the private key using openSSL by running:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -base64 -md md5 -pbkdf2 -nosalt --pass pass:71f0671db000ce238 -in cert.pem -out cert117.txt
```

I am able to get some text in cert117.txt file after running above command. However, when I use that to finally generate JWT, I am getting signature verification failed when checking in JWT.IO and also when trying to get the access token using the generated JWT. I have also tried `-aes-128-cbc` but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page that you linked shows the following private key example:

```
"privateKey": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n....\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

This is a PEM-formatted structure. In your question, you had called the file containing it `cert.txt` (why? it is a key, not a certificate). Assuming that it is called `private.pem` instead, you could interpret it with the following command:

```
$ openssl pkey -in private.pem -passin pass:71f0671db000ce238 -text -noout
```

Comment: Corrected question to reflect cert.pem. Thanks and tried above. Worked. Thankyou